# Difference between @Configuration @Bean and @RestController annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-webflux

I'm new to Java and the Spring framework. I would like to understand the difference between

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
```

and

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
```

I see people are using the above annotations to define the controllers in the application. I would like to understand what is the difference between them and when to use what.

In my case, I'm using the spring webflux framework so which is the most suitable annotation for defining the routers?

Any help is appreciatable :)

Answer (score 2):

**@Bean:**
In Spring, the objects that form the backbone of your application and that are managed by the Spring IoC container are called beans. A bean is an object that is instantiated, assembled, and otherwise managed by a Spring IoC container.

-->  Classes that have logic in them.  They do some business logic.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean

**@Configuration:**

Spring @Configuration annotation is part of the spring core framework. Spring Configuration annotation indicates that the class has @Bean definition methods. So Spring container can process the class and generate Spring Beans to be used in the application

https://www.journaldev.com/21033/spring-configuration-annotation

--> How you tell Spring that you have beans that need to setup.

**@RestController:**

The @RestController annotation was introduced in Spring 4.0 to simplify the creation of RESTful web services. It's a convenience annotation that combines @Controller and @ResponseBody – which eliminates the need to annotate every request handling method of the controller class with the @ResponseBody annotation.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller

--> If you have endpoints? You are definining an API, GET/POST/DELETE api interface for your business.  In those @Controller, you call your @Autowired beans (Services/Components) to do the business logic.

If there is another Application calling yours through the REST API? Then they call your @Controller Endpoints, (That is their main entry point to your system)